# mysqli_insert_id returns 0 constantly

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

can't make mysqli_insert_id work..
The id is `AUTO_INCREMENT` but still doesn't work.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO categoriasdivisiones (titulo, orden, descripcion, id_familiadivisiones) VALUES ('$titulo','$orden', '$descripcion', '$id_familia');";

    mysqli_query($base, $query);

    $ultimo_id = mysqli_insert_id($base);
```

Here i call the database:

```
include('../../../php/config.php');
```

the route is ok.

I know the problem in the code is the insert_id function because i have an image where i use this path:

```
move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], '../../../imagenes/categoriadivisiones/catdivisiones_'.$ultimo_id.'.'.$extensionfoto.'');
```

And the image is being saved as = catdivisiones_0.png

Hope you can help me.

```
CREATE TABLE `categoriasdivisiones` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text NOT NULL,
  `imagen` text NOT NULL,
  `orden` text NOT NULL,
  `id_familiadivisiones` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `categoriasdivisiones`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: The `mysqli_insert_id()` function returns the id (generated with `AUTO_INCREMENT`) used in the last query. Are you using auto increment?

Comment: Yes i am, "The id is A_I but still doesn't work."

Comment: I thought that was your format - you need to spell that out.

Comment: @JulianOsole, the statement 'The id is A_I but still doesn't work' doesn't make any sense to me. Autoincrement fields are ONLY integers.
Por favor, can you add your table creation script for categoriasdivisiones  into the question.

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($base)` return after the insert? If there is some error preventing the insert from happening, no insert_id can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

make sure $base variable has connection.after VALUES ('XX','XX','XX'XX').REMOVE ';'

The resultant query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO categoriasdivisiones (titulo, orden, descripcion, id_familiadivisiones) VALUES ('$titulo','$orden', '$descripcion', '$id_familia')";

mysqli_query($base, $query);

$ultimo_id = mysqli_insert_id($base);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this at the Create `id int auto_increment primary key` or you can select the latest record by the id `select id from your_table order by id DESC`
and store on a variable and sum +1 like this `<?php  $new_id =  $id_from_database + 1 ?>`

Hope i have helped